# How to add IP addresses in K8s NetworkPolicy dynamically

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have an egress `NetPol` ->

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: pod-egress-to-auth-endpoint
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: pod-a
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0 ## need to replace this with set of IP addresses allowed
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

Now , instead of keeping the pod open to all the IPs (cidr -> 0.0.0.0/0) , I want to restrict it to a set of IPs which will be coming from this url -

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Desired NetPol ->

```
 egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/x 
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/x 
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/x
```

So , Is there a way I can achieve this , read all thes IPs from a file , add them in the `NetworkPolicy` here programmatically ? i.e If we have 5 Ips , create 5 ipBlocks in NetPol.

Is it feasible to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

replace **x.x.x.x/x** with the list of IPs from the URL below

```
 egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/x 
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/x 
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/x
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , I'm aware we can use multiple ipBlock in order to achieve this , but how to do this dynamically ?? Let's say I have a list of IPs in a file , how can we use those IPs programmatically in NetPol.

Comment: you can use 

kubectl -n "${namespace}" patch NetworkPolicy "${np_name}" --type='json' -p="[{\"op\": \"replace\", \"path\": \"/spec/egress/0/to/0/ipBlock/cidr\", \"value\": \"${ip_blocks}\"}]"    @devcodes

Comment: Interesting , can you please update your answer with this command and explain what this command is doing ?

Comment: Understood you're replacing the path with some value...Got it...
In my case , since I want maybe more ipBlock , path will change accordingly I believe , correct ? @CoolNetworking

Comment: yes it should be like this 

kubectl -n "${namespace}" patch NetworkPolicy "${np_name}" --type='json' -p="[{\"op\": \"replace\", \"path\":  \"/spec/egress/0/to/0/ipBlock/cidr\", \"value\": \"${ip_blocks1}\"},{\"op\": \"replace\", \"path\":  \"/spec/egress/1/to/0/ipBlock/cidr\", \"value\": \"${ip_blocks2}\"}]" @devcodes

Comment: Thanks @CoolNetworking , is there any way to do with helm chart also ?

Comment: looks like operation add is not working in this json patch way, any idea why ?